# javascript/HTML changing an image with url(); not working as expected (EASY)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

quite simple, I think, but I'm missing something somewhere. I'm changing an image that is assigned in HTML like this:

```
<a href="properties-single.html" class="img" id="albumPhoto1" style="background-image: url(images/work-1.jpg);"></a>
```

to an image from a link in javascript with the following code snipet:

```
var x = 0
  var ids = ['albumPhoto1', 'songName1', 'artistName1',
             'albumPhoto2', 'songName2', 'artistName2',
             'albumPhoto3', 'songName3', 'artistName3'];
  data.tracks.items.map((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data.album.images[0].url)
      document.getElementById(ids[x]).style.backgroundImage = "url(data.album.images[0].url)";
      document.getElementById(ids[x + 1]).innerHTML = data.name;
      document.getElementById(ids[x + 2]).innerHTML = data.artists[0].name;
      x += 3;
}
```

This snipet is within something like a loop, running through an array of data about songs. My problem seems to be with

```
document.getElementById(ids[x]).style.backgroundImage = "url(data.album.images[0].url)";
```

but I don't know where. I can hard-code the link provided in console by the console.log above it and  works as expected, but as is it shows nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `data.album.images[0].url` is in the string as text, not code. Try:

```js
document.getElementById(ids[x]).style.backgroundImage = "url(" + data.album.images[0].url + ")";
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly, thank you. Will accept your answer in 10 minutes when it lets me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Using back quotes(`) instead of double quotes(") should work.

```
 document.getElementById(ids[x]).style.backgroundImage =`url(${data.album.images[0].url})`;
```

Comment: Warning: template strings [don't work on IE](https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals) so use caution